# How to stop ringtone when I open another activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

1. This is normal text
2. This is a list item

   TimePicker timePicker;
   Button StartAlarm,StopAlarm;
   TextView StartTime,CurrentTime,Questions;
   EditText Answers;

   Timer timer;
   MyTimerTask myTimerTask;

   int quest;

   private String Questionairs[] =
   {"What is PHP?", "What is HTML?", "What is CSS?"};
   private String QAnswer[] =
   {"Personal Home Page", "Hypertext Markup Language", "Cascading Style Sheet"};

   int randomizer = (int) (Math.random() * 2);

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ```
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
    StartAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartAlarm);
    StopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopAlarm);
    StartTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.StartTime);
    CurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CurrentTime);
    Questions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Questions);
    Answers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Answers);

    timer = new Timer();
    myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();


    final Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));




    StartAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int sTimeH = timePicker.getHour();
            int sTimeM = timePicker.getMinute();

            if(sTimeH < 10  &&  sTimeM < 10)
            {
                String holderH = String.valueOf(sTimeH);
                String holderM = String.valueOf(sTimeM);

                String AlarmTime = "0" + holderH + ":0" + holderM;
                StartTime.setText(AlarmTime);
            }
            else if(sTimeH > 10  &&  sTimeM < 10)
            {
                String holderH = String.valueOf(sTimeH);
                String holderM = String.valueOf(sTimeM);

                String AlarmTime = holderH + ":0" + holderM;
                StartTime.setText(AlarmTime);
            }
            else if(sTimeH < 10  &&  sTimeM > 10)
            {
                String holderH = String.valueOf(sTimeH);
                String holderM = String.valueOf(sTimeM);

                String AlarmTime = "0" + holderH + ":" + holderM;
                StartTime.setText(AlarmTime);
            }

            else{
                String holderH = String.valueOf(sTimeH);
                String holderM = String.valueOf(sTimeM);

                String AlarmTime = holderH + ":" + holderM;
                StartTime.setText(AlarmTime);
            }

            if(timer != null){
                timer.cancel();
            }

            timer = new Timer();
            myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

            timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000, 1000);

            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (CurrentTime.getText().toString().equals(StartTime.getText().toString())){
                        r.play();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 1000);

    }
   ```

   });

   ```
    StopAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Questions.setText(Questionairs[0]);
            Answers.setEnabled(true);



            if(Answers.getText().toString().equals(QAnswer[0]) && Questions.getText().toString().equals((Questionairs[0])))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomePage.class);
                startActivity(i);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
   ```

}
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                CurrentTime.setText(strDate);
            }});
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some more time to make your question clearer and format your code to be more readable.

Comment: @Jayson112 if my answer helped you, please mark it correct so that rest of the community can use it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add `r.stop()` when you start the activity and intent flags should be set before `startActivity(intent)`.

```
if(Answers.getText().toString().equals(QAnswer[0]) && Questions.getText().toString().equals((Questionairs[0])))
         {
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomePage.class);
             i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
             startActivity(i);
             r.stop();
             finish();
         }
```